# How to check multiple variables against multiple columns in a Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am getting 3 variables:

- period : datetime as in '2022-11-01 00:00:00'
- file_name  : string as in 'File_001'
- file_creation : datetime as in '2022-09-19 00:00:00'

And I need to check if there is any line in a DataFrame that matches all 3 criteria in the same line, for example (this is the Excel File imported with Pandas).

```
Doc Period     Document  CreationDate
1   11/1/2022  File_001  9/19/2022
2   11/1/2022  File_002  9/19/2022
3   11/1/2022  File_003  9/19/2022
4   11/1/2022  File_001  9/25/2022
```

As you may see, there are 2 "File_001" for Period "11/1/2022" yet they differ in the CreationDate. In this example, it should match with Doc 1. If it would not match, it would return False or something to let me know it is new to the DataFrame.

I tried creating new DF with each criteria like
`new_df = df[df['Period' == period]` - > but this Fails (I think it is related to the TimeStamp format)

And then continue shrinking this new_df until all criteria are included. If there is a row included, I would know that there already is a row matching all criteria.

I would welcome other ideas less costly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# Return matched rows using loc
def match_rows (df, period, doc, creation):
    return df.loc[df['Period'].eq(pd.to_datetime(period)) &
           df['Document'].eq(doc) &
           df['CreationDate'].eq(pd.to_datetime(creation))]


# convert the dates to datetime format
df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Period'])
df['CreationDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CreationDate'])


match_rows(df, '2022-11-01', 'File_001', '2022-09-19')
```

```
Doc     Period  Document    CreationDate
0   1   2022-11-01  File_001    2022-09-19
```